# How to know when dissolution is complete?

Tags: equilibrium, precipitation

In a given solubility equilibrium, I know that if $ Q >K_s$, then the salt will precipitate until $ Q =K_s$. If $ Q <K_s$, however, would the precipitate dissolve until $ Q =K_s$ too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've described the general tendency for any equilibrium process, including solubility. So, the short answer is yes, you will dissolve more until the reaction quotient is equal to the equilibrium constant.